# Conda, how can I activate an specefic env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I'm trying to use `conda activate <env>` in my vscode's terminal. But nothing seems to work.

[image]

I have two environments, `SharkiPyTorch` and `base`, only the first one has `Opencv` installed. Despite of that I didn't get any response from using `conda activate base`. I tried to execute my `example.py` file, using both environments but I just got an error saying that the module OpenCV is missing.

I used the `conda list` for both environments and I checked that I have Opencv in one of them.

I don't know why I can't select my environments.

[image]

VScode is using Python's conda path.

I just noticed that doing `code .` in conda's terminal in the folder path, I can load my proyect from my environment and it works, nevertheless I'd like to be able to use commands for my environments from my Vscode's terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSCode terminal "powershell" does not automatically activate the conda environment by default. I use the command "`conda init powershell`" to make it automatically activate the conda environment: (please open a new terminal)

[image]

Then, we can use the command "`conda activate XXX`" to activate other conda environments:

[image]